# Doctrine ORM relations in Symfony/API Platform

Tags: symfony, orm, api-platform.com

I have been on this for 3 days now. I have two entities named **plan** and **planRequirements**.
The plan contains requirements which would be pre-populated with requirements and tends to be modified with additional requirements without altering the pre-populated requirements.

This is the plan entity

```
#[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    #[ApiProperty(identifier:false)]
    private $id;

    #[Groups(["plan:read", "plan:write"])]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer', nullable: true)]
    #[ApiProperty(identifier:true)]
    private $planId;

    #[Groups(["plan:read", "plan:write"])]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'json', nullable: true)]
    #[ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity: PlanRequirement::class, inversedBy: 'requirements')]
    private $requirements = [];

    #[Groups(["plan:read", "plan:write"])]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'json', nullable: true)]
    private $scope = [];
```

for the PlanRequirements entity

```
    #[ORM\Id, ORM\GeneratedValue, ORM\Column(type:"integer")]
    #[ApiProperty(identifier:false)]
    private $id;

    #[Groups("plan:read")]
    #[ORM\Column(type:"integer")]
    #[ApiProperty(identifier:true)]
    private $planId;

   #[Groups("plan:read")]
   #[ORM\OneToOne( mappedBy: 'requirement', targetEntity: Plan::class)]
   #[ORM\Column(type: 'json', nullable: true)]
    private $requirements = [];
```

***The relation isn't embedded in the plan endpoint***. I made sure that the planId on both entities have the same content.
What I am trying to achieve is similar to usual SQL join i.e.

SELECT plan.planId, plan.requirements, plan.scope, PlanRequirements.requirements from plan JOIN requirements ON plan.planId = PlanRequirements.planId;

Thank you

Comment: As a general rule, a description such as `didn't work` is not particularly useful.

Comment: Thank you @Cerad I have made a change to it.